# Is this imply that this problem of twin primes is Partially Decidable

Tags: computability, computational-mathematics

I find this equivalence:

Partially Decidable Problem $⇔$ Recursively Enumerable Set

I know that the set of twin primes is a recursively enumerable set. Is this imply that the problem of the existence of infinitely many twin primes is **Partially Decidable**.

Comment: Could you include in question to statement and or proof of the equivalence you state?

Comment: @coffeemath: I find it in this link: https://basics.sjtu.edu.cn/~yuxi/teaching/computability2013/slides/9.%20Recursively%20Enumerable%20Set.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the link, Germany.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The reason for this is because there is no known way to detect if there are infinitely many twin primes even though we can find twin primes in a recursively enumerable way. So the problem of enumerating the twin primes is recursively enumerable but the problem of deciding if there are finitely many or infinitely many isn't by any known algorithm.

Comment: Is there are any proof for the last phrase of your answer.

Comment: @Germany If the twin prime conjecture had an algorithm to decide it we would have solved the twin prime conjecture. If someone had found one we'd call it the twin prime theorem.

Comment: So the difference is related about finding an algorithm.

Comment: @Germany exactly. Some algorithm might exist. If we could solve the halting problem then we could solve the twin prime conjecture by asking if the enumeration halts. Unfortunately that's not possible so we have to find another approach.